# How can I get my App.xaml in one project to see a different project?

Tags: xaml, binding, silverlight-5.0

In my Silverlight Business application I have 3 projects - the two standard (AppName and AppName.Web) and I have a Silverlight Class Library named ModelClasses.

AppName  (App.xaml is here)
AppName.Web
ModelClasses

I would like to be able to bind to the values in ModelClasses in the xaml files in AppName, is it even possible? In App.xaml I have tried `xmlns:mc="clr-namespace:ModelClasses"` but it won't work.

I am definitely missing something here so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you referenced your ModelClasses project from your AppName project?

Comment: Yeah, this is why I'm confused that it's not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also provide a reference to the assembly,

```
xmlns:mc="clr-namespace:ModelClasses;assembly=ModelClasses"
```

More on Silverlight namespace mapping [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Superb, I knew there was something obvious I was missing! Thank you